# I cannot get any results to display with this code

Tags: php

I get "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given" when I use this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, time, age FROM friends WHERE age = " .$age. "limit 0, 10";

$secquery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($secquery) > 0){

  while($row = $secquery->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "This person === ".$row['name']. " matched your age, which is " .$row['age']. '<br>';

  }
}
```

I'm trying to match records in my db with the entered record.  I've tried everything.  A little help?

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your query. Try typing `mysqli_error($conn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT name, time, age FROM friends WHERE age='$age' limit 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the connection string $conn already?

```
 <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```